# Inconstant panel placement with jquery + bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a custom RSS dashboard and I am iterating over an array of feeds and throwing them to the google service.

but when I look at my panels they are not in order consistently.

code:

JQuery

```
 var rssArray = [
  'https://blog.malwarebytes.org/feed/',
  'http://krebsonsecurity.com/feed/',
  'http://motherboard.vice.com/rss?trk_source=motherboard',
  'https://www.trustwave.com/rss.aspx?type=twblog',
  'http://threatpost.com/feed/',
  'https://news.ycombinator.com/rss',
  'http://feeds.trendmicro.com/TrendMicroSimplySecurity?format=xml',
  'https://securityintelligence.com/topics/vulnerabilities-threats/feed/',
  'https://securityintelligence.com/topics/x-force/feed/'
]
   for (var i=0; i < rssArray.length; i++){
     $.ajax({
       url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(rssArray[i]),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
        //  console.log(data)
         var feedBody = $('<div>', {class: 'panel-body'})
         var feedHead = $('<div>', {class: 'panel-heading', html: '<h3 class="panel-title text-center">'+capitaliseFirstLetter(data.responseData.feed.title)+'</h3>'})
         var contentHolder = $('<ul>', {class: 'list-group'})
         var feed = $('<div>', {class: 'col-xs-6 col-md-4 panel panel-warning'}).append(feedHead).append(feedBody).append(contentHolder)
         $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(key, value){
           if (value.contentSnippet === "Comments"){
             var thehtml = '<a href="'+value.link+'" target="_blank" class="list-group-item"><h5 class="list-group-item-heading">'+value.title+'</h5></a>';
           } else {
             var thehtml = '<a href="'+value.link+'" target="_blank" class="list-group-item"><h5 class="list-group-item-heading">'+value.title+'</h5><p class="list-group-item-text">'+value.contentSnippet+'</p></a>';
           }
           feedBody.append(thehtml)
         });
        $("#content").append(feed)
       }
    })
 }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="row">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Examples of issues:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kicking off a series of AJAX calls, which **will execute for an unknown amount of time**. When they complete they will call their success callbacks.

If the first request takes 5 seconds, but the third request takes 2, the third request will be rendered before the first.

If you need to ensure that these requests have all completed before rendering their contents, use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to create a promise (jQuery deferred actually) and render all the data when it has resolved.